# Is there a way to use "alt" tag with image sprites? I cannot get get the alt text to not overwrite the images that show up

Tags: html, css

** This is a short sample of my code. There are a bunch of buttons with icons, all using the "alt" tag. I validated all code using the NU HTML Checker and it indicated "no issues or warnings". Then when I opened it in Firefox, the alt text was overprinting all the images, which are sprites. Pretty sure it has to do with the "background", but is there not a way to overcome this? The issue never showed up until I opened in Firefox, so I also tried Chrome...same result.**

```css
#mintscandies {
  width: 170px;
  height: 160px;
  background: url(https://www.texasbranderspromotional.com/files/color-home-page-sprites-07022022.jpg) -20px -20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div id="mintscandies">
      <img src="https://www.sagemember.com/we/we.dll/img_trans.gif" alt="custom branded mint candies" width="1" height="1">
    </div>
    <button class="dropbtn">MINT CANDIES</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="https://www.texasbranderspromotional.com/breath-mints.htm">Popular Breath Mints</a>
      <a href="https://www.texasbranderspromotional.com/breath-mints-wrapped.htm">Full Color Wrapper Mints</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://www.sagemember.com/we/we.dll/img_trans.gif is not valid - 404. `alt` will only display when the image cannot load.

Comment: Using your browser’s dev tool inspect facility should help you track down problems. You’ll see that the src for the img can not be found. So the system will revert to alt text. I can’t see that this has anything to do with the background sprite.

Comment: The problem is that the "alt text" shows up all the time, overlaying the images. So, I have the images, but then there is the black alt text overlaying it. The only workaround I have found is to just forget the alt text and put <...alt=""...> which obviously does nothing for SEO or when the images do not load somewhere. That way google cannot downgrade us for not having the alt tag, which is something new  - they want every site to be absolutely 100% perfect as per their guidelines, and if not, they may not even index it.